# Ansible Tower tasks logs and job views

Tags: ansible-tower

I am evaluating Ansible Tower. The key aspect I am focusing on is the logging: ansible output traces are difficult to check, Ansible Tower should bring among other things a nice view of green spots for each executed tasks of a playbook. Except it is not. I designed a very simple playbook with "debug" tasks, I execute it with Ansible Tower. I have the job view with the text output, the details view displaying key aspects, such as the status, but I cannot see the detail status of each and every task as displayed in the demo video at the following link: https://youtu.be/wZ_mh4-4HPY?t=540, with the continuous update in real time.

Here is a screen capture of what I see:

[image: Screen Capture]

Is it a limitation of the trial version? If not, what am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: So what do you see?

Comment: I just edited the post to add a screen capture. In the demo video in the link I pasted, the screen is scrollable and you can see the result of each individual task, with color code. You can replay a particular task. In my version, I don't see any of this.

Comment: You can't scroll the page down? Have you cleared your cache? tried another browser?

Comment: I tried with Google Chrome and Firefox. I just installed Ansible Tower version 3.8.3. Are you talking about the browser cache, or the Tower cache? I am a bit new to this. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I meant the browser cache.

Comment: I just did, and I still missing the scroll bar. I consulted an existing job and ran another one, I have the same result.